# Better ways to stop all future calls when there is no internet Connectivity

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I want to stop all the future ajax calls when there is no internet connectivity. I know the 
$rootScope.isOnline = navigator.onLine; line to check either user is online/offline.

Is there anything I can add in $httpProvider.interceptors, and stop all calls and show only one alert-message to user that you are not connected with the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
var module = angular.module("app", []);
module.factory("ConnectivityService", function ($window) {
    var service = {
        connected: true
    };
    $window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
        alert("offline");
        service.connected = false;

    });
    $window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
        alert("online");
        service.connected = true;

    });
    return service;
});
module.factory("ConnectedInterceptor", function ($q, ConnectivityService) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            if (ConnectivityService.connected) {
                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
            return $q.reject(config);
        }
    };
});
module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('ConnectedInterceptor');
});
```

Altough this navigator.onLine is pretty unreliable :/

Answer (score 1):

This is in Javascript, not JQuery.

Create a boolean, and evaluate it each time you do internet requests.

Create a ping function, just to another file, to test for internet connectivity. Set the boolean to false if it doesn't make it.

Just a really simple idea... call it periodically or every time you make a vital internet call.